# Best approach to use swagger generated data-models in business logic app

Tags: python, flask, swagger, connexion

I have a Python program which encapsulates the business logic of an app. 
An example:

```
$ app pets list
[{
 "name": "Hasso",
 "age": 21
},{
 "name": "Lassy",
 "age": 15
 }]
```

Now I want to realize a REST API with [Swagger.io](http://swagger.io). An extract of the YAML looks like this:

```
 summary: Gets all dogs 
  produces:
  - application/json
  responses:
    200:
      description: array of dogs
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Dog'
```

Swagger-codgen generates python code using Flask & [connexion](https://github.com/zalando/connexion) and provides the following directory structure:

```
└── python-flask
    └── swagger_server
        ├── controllers
        ├── models
        ├── __pycache__
        ├── swagger
        └── test
```

There are classes for all used object types in the `models`-directory.

I want to keep the API-App and the BL-App(business app) separate but use the same models for convenience.

What's the best way of sharing the model definitions in-between these to applications? I will also import this BL-App into the API-Project in order to implement the `controllers`-part.

Comment: A 'superior user' might want to create the [connexion] tag...

Comment: FWIW, for my projects, I've found I prefer the [`bravado`](https://bravado.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library, which generates model types from the `swagger.yaml`/`swagger.json` of the API server on the fly. That also neatly sidesteps the issue of where to store the generated classes.